# Keywords and domain

Tags: seo

I have found that one of the keywords I would like to be found in the search engine has a domain that I can register. This is not a good name for the general project, and so not for all the web, but it is a good definition or explanation of a part. Is it a good idea to register something like this just to point it to a section of the web? I mean is this effective from the SEO point of view? but most important, is it a good practice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, in therms of SEO, this is NOT a good practice, and google can punish your website (so i'd not recommend it), but...
...if this word is really easy to remember and you think the user will try it to access your site without needing to search for it, it may be "acceptable", because you won't lose online visits.
Anyway.. you should avoid black hat techniques.

Comment: Would it be correct to have a domain for each section of the same web?I mean the domain, the title and the h1 would be the same in each section.

Comment: I'd recommend you to not to do this.. the title tag is one of the most important tags for SEO, so you should work a little more to find a small phrase to define this tag (and yes, u can put the keyword domain in it, but not only this, do you get?

Comment: for the h1 tag, u should do the same... take a look at this example for the <title> tag I found on the internet: For example, if your company is "Johnson and Smith Inc.," a tax accounting firm in Texas, you would want your company's site to appear in the search engine results for searches on phrases such as "Texas tax accountants" and "CPAs in Texas." (Be sure to do your keyword research to find the best phrases!) If you prefer to work with people only in the Dallas area, you'd need to be even more specific by adding geographical modifiers to your title tags, such as "Dallas tax accountants."

Comment: all the tags must be well planned when we're dealing with SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Google updates "Panda", "Penguin" later versions discourage this type of technique. Naming your domain as same to the specific research like www.healthcaremedicine.com. That means if someone search for the products health care medicine. Your website is shown at top.
I think that is what you mean. 
In past years people name their website closer to the search result but now it is not recommended. It may for some time take your site to top. But that will not last long. Your site should have to provide what it promise its visitors. At least they have to spend some time.

Answer (score 0):

Exact Match Domain is what you are referring to, as answered above is not advisable, but if you find it useful you can register and go ahead. 
How to keep you off from penalties.

1. Do not stuff KW's in title and descriptions, as your domain already has the KW
2. When doing off-page SEO, Do not choose anchor text as your Main KW, instead use URL itself as anchor text and some generic anchor text like click here, more info, read more.

These can save you from penalty. I still see a lot of EMD's ranking just by being careful with the usage of KW's and anchor text.